# Websocket. Раздельное подключение

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Есть админка с бэком на ноде. Суть: пользователь авторизуется. Вводит ссылку на сайт. Нажимает старт -> запрос на сервер -> запускается селениум -> между селениумом и клиентом образуется соединение по вебсокетам -> селениум отсылает данные на фронт.

**Суть вопроса: зашёл с 2 разных аккаунтов. Ввёл ссылку на 1 из них и запустил. Вебсокеты начали слать данные 2 аккаунтам. Я же хочу, чтобы они слали только инициатору запроса. Что для этого надо?**

На сервере стоит обработчик сокетов на порте 8080. Соответственно клиенту я тоже указываю этот порт. Надо как-то динамически его изменять для каждого из пользователй?

Comment: я так понимаю, нужно держать массив всех подключенных пользователей с уникальным идентификатором, и отправлять сообщения только по нему

Comment: @Дмытрык, можно немного подробнее? Каким образом получить этот идентификатор? Этот массив хранить в базе данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const userOnline = {};

wsServer.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
  const id = Math.random();
  userOnline[id] = ws;
  setInterval(() => {
    sendMessageToUser(id)
  }, 2000)
})

function sendMessageToUser(id) {
  userOnline[id].send('message', "I'am here")
}
```

Хранить ли массив идентификаторов онлайн-юзеров в БД - нет. Кроме идентификатора, Вам же еще необходимо хранить данные самого подключения, чтобы иметь возможность отправить сообщение пользователю

Comment: Попробовал ваш способ. Сервер запоминает подключаемых клиентов, но почему-то не отсылает месседж на клиент

Comment: И ещё такой вопрос, если пользователь обновит страницу, то у него устанавливается новый идентификатор. Это нормально?

Comment: На счет вопроса - это нормально. Но Вам необходимо обработать эту ситуацию... удалить id закрытого соединению. Что же касается не отправки сообщений - сложно сказать, должно работать, хоть код и не приследовал такой цели)

Comment: продебажил: селениум отправляет месседж, а сервер возвращает его назад, и клиенту оно не доходит)